# PHP Github API: Get repository informations

Tags: php, symfony, github, web-crawler

I'm building a page to show some specific repositories. The informations I need to know is the **author, the description and the current version**. Sure, I could crawl the github repository page and find the div with this information, but if Github changes the HTML my crawler would be usless. So I'm searching a **official method to get this informations with PHP**. Is there a solution out there for this case? I am using symfony.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Git hub provides a large set of APIs. You can use them and explore the github related information for your account.
https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: Could you please provide a code example with the requirements?